# Checking Object keys set with value against another Object keys

Tags: validation, typescript

I'm willing to check an an object's values in typescript, based on another object's keys.
The mental model is "the key exists, it's not an object, is the value in obj set, otherwise, it's an object, iterate again".

What would be your recommandations about this simple snippet :

```js
/**
 * Returns an array. If the array is empty, the checked obj is fine.
 * Otherwise it's not.
 * 
 * @remarks
 * areValuesSet(obj, rules).length === 0 is the test to make.
 * 
 * @param obj {object} - object to verify
 * @param rules {object} - object containing the keys to check against
 * @returns {string[]} - array of incorrect keys
 */
const areValuesSet = (
  obj: { [propKey: string]: any },
  rules: { [propKey: string]: any }
): string[] =>
  Object.keys(rules).reduce((prev, key) => {
    if (typeof rules[key] === "object" && typeof obj[key] === "object") {
      return areValuesSet(obj[key], rules[key]);
    }

    return !obj ||
      !obj[key] ||
      (isEmpty(obj[key]) && typeof obj[key] !== 'boolean')
      ? [...prev, key]
      : [...prev];
  }, []);
```

I would enhance this with a "validator" function which would call `areValuesSet` like so :

```js
/**
 * Call `rulesParser` and checks the returned value length equals 0
 *
 * @param obj {object} - object to verify
 * @param rulesObj {object} - object containing the keys to check against
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
export const validateRules = (
  obj: { [propKey: string]: any },
  rulesObj: { [propKey: string]: any }
): boolean => rulesParser(obj, rulesObj).length === 0;
```

Thank you

Comment: To validate, are you hoping that all primitive values in the input (possibly nested inside objects) are *numbers*? Is that the logic you wish to perform?

Comment: No I want to have primitives with no empty value.

Comment: I updated with lodash.isempty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Function and parameter names** The function name `areValuesSet` could be more precise. It returns an array of incorrect property names, not a boolean of if values are set. Maybe call it `getIncorrectProperties`? Also, the argument named `obj` is uninformative. You want to indicate that it's the target value being checked. Maybe call it `validateTarget` or something similar.

**Avoid `any`** `any` is type-unsafe. Unless you have a really good reason for it, better to type something you don't know about as `unknown` instead. `unknown` is similar to `any`, but requires you to do type-narrowing first. In this case, using `unknown` will point out a bug in your current logic:

**typeof null gives object** You have:

```
if (typeof rules[key] === "object" && typeof obj[key] === "object") {
  return areValuesSet(obj[key], rules[key]);
}
```

This will result in the recursive call throwing if one of the values happens to be `null`, since `null` is an object. Add in and call:

```
const isObject = (arg: unknown) => typeof arg === 'object' && arg !== null;
```

**`!obj[key]` excludes `false`** Your current logic permits values of `true` but forbids values of `false` due to this check:

```
!obj[key] || (isEmpty(obj[key]) && typeof obj[key] !== 'boolean')
```

Is that deliberate? It's OK if it is, but it may well be a logic bug. If `false` should indeed be excluded, then `typeof obj[key] !== 'boolean'` simplifies to `obj[key] !== true`.

**Nested property bugs**

(1) The recursive call is only entered if *both* the rules and target are objects. If the rule is an object, and the target is a non-empty non-object, the target will pass, when it probably shouldn't. Eg:

```
// rules:
{
  prop: { val: 'val' }
}

// target:
{
  prop: 'foo'
}
```

should probably fail, but won't. If the rule is an object and the target value is not an object, you probably want to push the property to the array of errors.

(2) When a sub-object is found as a value, your `reduce` callback does:

```
return areValuesSet(obj[key], rules[key]);
```

Whatever may have been put into the accumulator array on prior iterations will be lost, since it's not being factored into the return value. For example, if you had a data structure for which the first 5 properties were wrong, but the 6th property is nested and correct, the function would return an empty array.

But `reduce` arguably [isn't very appropriate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaGjS7-qWzg) in these sorts of situations anyway - see that link for a video by Chrome developers on the subject. It introduces an annoying amount of boilerplate code, especially in TS, and even well-formulated `reduce`s like these often aren't entirely trivial to understand at a glance.

Consider creating an array outside the function and pushing to it instead - or use a recursive function which creates the array to return as a default argument when not passed. Including all the other suggestions as well:

```
type GenericObj = { [propKey: string]: unknown };
const isObject = (arg: unknown): arg is GenericObj => typeof arg === 'object' && arg !== null;

const getIncorrectProperties = (
  validateTarget: GenericObj,
  rules: GenericObj,
  incorrectProperties: string[] = [],
) => {
  for (const [key, ruleValue] of Object.entries(rules)) {
    const targetValue = validateTarget[key];
    if (isObject(ruleValue)) {
      if (!isObject(targetValue)) {
        incorrectProperties.push(key);
      } else {
        getIncorrectProperties(targetValue, ruleValue, incorrectProperties);
      }
    } else if (!targetValue || (isEmpty(targetValue) && targetValue !== true)) {
      incorrectProperties.push(key);
    }
  }
  return incorrectProperties;
};
```

Live snippet of compiled code including example validation, to show that it's working:

```js
"use strict";
const isObject = (arg) => typeof arg === 'object' && arg !== null;
const getIncorrectProperties = (validateTarget, rules, incorrectProperties = []) => {
    for (const [key, ruleValue] of Object.entries(rules)) {
        const targetValue = validateTarget[key];
        if (isObject(ruleValue)) {
            if (!isObject(targetValue)) {
                incorrectProperties.push(key);
            }
            else {
                getIncorrectProperties(targetValue, ruleValue, incorrectProperties);
            }
        }
        else if (!targetValue || (_.isEmpty(targetValue) && targetValue !== true)) {
            incorrectProperties.push(key);
        }
    }
    return incorrectProperties;
};
console.log(getIncorrectProperties({
    prop2: {
        nested: 'val',
    }
}, {
    prop1: true,
    prop2: {
        nested: true,
        nested2: {
            deeplyNested: true
        }
    },
    prop3: true
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The only issue I have with the above code is the `incorrectProperties` argument. Although the approach works to create an array on initial call and return it at the end, having it as a parameter might be confusing, since the initial call should not take 3 arguments, only 2. If you think that's not acceptable, you could create an array in the function body on every call and return it at the end, and spread the result of the recursive call into that array.

Comment: Thank you, clear solution. I'm being more aware that I'm over using reduce method. Btw, I opt for a function scoped declaration of `incorrectProperties `. Thank you again